# Multiple conditionally GROUP BY and COUNT using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First I'm sorry for my bad English and sorry for not providing the code that because I'm using my phone and my code is on my office PC. I have been searching on Google and trying to use `UNION` but the result is not as I expected. Please, help me solve this problem.

#### I have this visit table on my mysql:

```
| date              | merchant     | itemid |  act      | result |
|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| 2015-07-19        | 3G Power     | 100    | visit     | OK     |
| 2015-07-19        | 3G Power     | 101    | visit     | OK     |
| 2015-07-19        | Anamely      | 200    | visit     | OK     |
| 2015-07-19        | Anamely      | 201    | visit     | OK     |
| 2015-07-19        | Anamely      | 202    | visit     | NOK    |
| 2015-07-19        | Anamely      | 203    | repair    | NOK    |
| 2015-07-20        | Garden Bay   | 300    | visit     | OK     |
| 2015-07-20        | Garden Bay   | 301    | install   | OK     |
| 2015-07-20        | Anamely      | 203    | repair    | OK     |
```

#### This is `UNION` that I have tried:

```
create view allvisit (date, merchant, act, result, itemqty) as
select date, merchant, act, 'OK', count(itemid) from visit where result='OK' group by merchant
union
select date, merchant, act, 'NOK', count(itemid) from visit where result='NOK' group by merchant
```

#### And my expected result in html table is:

```
| date              | merchant     |  act      | result | itemqty |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| 2015-07-19        | 3G Power     | visit     | OK      | 2      |
|                   | Anamely      | visit     | OK      | 2      |
|                   | Anamely      | visit     | NOK     | 1      |
|                   | Anamely      | repair    | NOK     | 1      |
| 2015-07-20        | Garden Bay   | visit     | OK      | 1      |
|                   | Garden Bay   | install   | OK      | 1      |
|                   | Anamely      | repair    | OK      | 1      |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
|     total work day.               | 2 days | tot qty| 9 items   |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
```

So the condition is date only show on first column and first row for each same date, merchant name only shows once for each `act` and result and uses `count by itemid` => `itemqty` for more than one. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: @Daan: spamming? how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to explain...i just do try and error edited from @beiller answer...

#### this is SQL work for my expected result :

```
create view allvisit (date, merchant, act, result, itemqty) as
select min(date) as date, merchant, act, 'OK', count(itemid) from visit where result='OK' group by merchant,act
union
select min(date) as date, merchant, act, 'NOK', count(itemid) from visit where result='NOK' group by merchant,act
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give this a shot. Selecting the status is tricky so I've used MAX function.

```
select
  MIN(date),
  merchant,
  act,
  MAX(result),
  count(itemid) as itemqty
from MYTABLE 
GROUP BY merchant, act
```

Comment: Yes it reveals a problem with your data. What are the specific rules you need to determine whether it is OK or NOK? Is it the status of the group with the highest "itemid"? Or does NOK just trump OK all the time?

Comment: No...OK and NOK is the result from act that technical support do when visit the merchant on that date...so the visit table above mean on date 2015-07-19, techincal support visited 3G Power merchant to maintenance(i call it visit) that have 2 item and both of them result OK and on same date also go to Anamely merchant that have 4 item to do visit for 3 item and repair 1 item with result 2 visit action is OK, 1 visit is NOK and 1 repair is NOK...because repair act is NOK on that date, technical support back to anamely merchant again on 2015-07-20 and this time the result is OK, on this date tech

Comment: On this date technical support also go to Garden Bay merchant to do visit for 1 item and install for 1 new item with both result is OK